# How can I set up a simple Ruby app?

Tags: ruby

This should be surprisingly simple, but it eludes me. I'm trying to set up a simple command such that I can type: `ruby myfile someparams` and it will return something via stdio.

I want to include a `gem`, like https://rubygems.org/gems/github-linguist and pass something to it and see what it has as a response.

I'm a bit lost. Ideas?

Comment: Linux / OS X will be the build target

Comment: Put the ruby script somewhere on your PATH, add the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` as the first line, and make the file executable with `chmod`.

Comment: And what about the rest? Accepting arguments, etc?

Comment: Ruby has `ARGV` as a builtin variable.  That's an array containing any command-line arguments.

Comment: Make an answer so I can accept

Comment: If you've already installed Ruby, it's as easy as running `ruby my_app arguments..` from the directory your script is in and have your script reference `ARGV` for arguments. This information is very easily Googled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample script that just echoes its arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "The arguments were:"
ARGV.each { |curr_arg| puts curr_arg }
```

Save this to `foo.rb`, then `chmod a+x foo.rb`.  You can either move it to some location on your PATH, in which case you can just type `foo.rb some args` from anywhere, or you can run it explicitly from the current directory with either `./foo.rb some args` or `ruby foo.rb some args`.